# Inversify throws "Ambiguous match found for serviceIdentifier" when a second binding is attempted

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, inversifyjs

Did my diligence and the following are not the scenario I am experiencing.

- [InversifyJS @multiInject not working, throws error "Ambiguous match found for serviceIdentifier"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61298521/inversifyjs-multiinject-not-working-throws-error-ambiguous-match-found-for-se)
- [Using Inversify to do a Multiinject of a class with constant and injected parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46846883/using-inversify-to-do-a-multiinject-of-a-class-with-constant-and-injected-parame)

Also referred to the [Official MultiInject Documentation](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/multi_injection.md).

---

In my `inversify.config.ts` file I have the following

```
const SAContainer = new Container();

// Bot Command Handler bindings
SAContainer.bind<ICommandHandler>(TYPES.CommandHandlers).to(AboutCommand);
SAContainer.bind<ICommandHandler>(TYPES.CommandHandlers).to(AccountAgeCommand);
```

And both files are as follows:

```
@injectable()
export class AboutCommand implements ICommandHandler {
  // ...
}

@injectable()
export class AccountAgeCommand implements ICommandHandler {
  // ...
}
```

The exception that is thrown is:

```
Error: Ambiguous match found for serviceIdentifier: CommandHandlers
Registered bindings:
 AboutCommand
 AccountAgeCommand
 ...stack trace excluded
```

When I uncomment one of the bindings, so that there is only one, it works as expected. But when I attempt to bind 2 or more in this fashion, I get the error message. What have I missed?

The error is thrown the when the first dependency is pulled. In the application this is the application object and composition root.

```
SAContainer.bind<App>(App).toSelf().inSingletonScope();

const application = SAContainer.get<App>(App); // Error thrown here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was apparently a single class that escaped code analysis and search due to not adhering to the use of the `TYPES` object. This class implemented an injection that was causing this issue.

Problem code:

```ts
@injectable()
export class RaidHandler implements IRaidStreamEvent {
    constructor(
        @inject(ApiClient) private apiClient: ApiClient,
>>      @inject('CommandHandlers') commandHandlers: shoutoutCommand,
        @inject(TYPES.Logger) private logger: winston.Logger,
    ) {
```

Since this did not adhere to the accepted practice used in the code base, this bug hid from me and those involved in searching it down.